# overloading operators not asigning given values

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn how overloading works and ended up with strange problem. When i run this code it works perfectly fine for the first object but doesn't get any values for the second obj and assignes default ones.
so output is:

podaj liczbe w postaci (a,b)

(2,3) //input

(2, 3) //output

podaj liczbe w postaci (a,b)

(4,5) //input

(0, 0) //output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Complex{
   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Complex& );
   friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Complex& );
public:
   explicit Complex(double = 0.0, double = 0.0);
   Complex operator+(const Complex&) const;
   Complex operator-(const Complex&) const;
private:
   double real;
   double imaginary;
};

Complex::Complex(double re, double im):real(re),imaginary(im){}

Complex Complex::operator+(const Complex &operand2) const{
   return Complex(real + operand2.real, imaginary + operand2.imaginary);
}

Complex Complex::operator-(const Complex& operand2) const {
   return Complex(real - operand2.real, imaginary - operand2.imaginary);
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Complex &number){
   output << "(" << number.real << ", " << number.imaginary << ")" << endl;
   return output;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& input, Complex& number) {

   input.ignore();
   input >> number.real;
   input.ignore();
   input >> number.imaginary;
   input.ignore();

   return input;
}

int main(){
   Complex a;
   cout << "podaj liczbe w postaci (a,b)\n";
   cin >> a;
   cout << a;

   Complex b;
  cout << "podaj liczbe w postaci (a,b)\n";
  cin >> b;
  cout << b;
}
```

Comment: Add one more `input.ignore();` so you have 2 `input.ignore();` after you read to `number.imaginary`

Comment: Ty it works, but can you tell my why this was happening?

Comment: Simply because you need to ignore `ENTER` just like you do with `(`, `,` and `)`